# Writing modular classes

Tags: macros, external-files, package-writing, documentclass-writing

As an OOP programmer, I am very attracted to the idea of making separate files for independent features within a class definition, where each feature I feel is too long to be included inline in the class but is too short or has class dependencies that disqualify it from being a standalone package. Is this a good practice? If so, how can I write parts of classes in separate files?

Comment: By making sub features in packages. See how the beamer class is organized.

Comment: @daleif: What so you mean by "sub features"?

Comment: I think KOMA classes show some sophisticated features and LaTeX3 with its templates - features

Comment: The features/macros you want to factor out into its own package.

Comment: The question didn't get a lot of attention yet, can you extend the question a bit? Did you look at the `beamer` package?  Right now, the question seems to be a bit unclear.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I just separated the code into packages, like `beamer`.

Comment: @daleif Wanna write a bit concerning the beamer approach?

Comment: @SimonKuang It would be nice to give some feedback to the commentors, so they can actually write an answer. A future user might come here and just sees comments, or the question, while maybe useful, is closed because it is not answerable. Would be a pity. So, helpers need your support as well to make the whole site as useful for others as possible.

Comment: @Johannes_B, that is true. Feedback time: I ended up using daleif's solution, which is just to split up functional units into local packages.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question. With the feedback the OP has given, the question can be answered, and i hope @daleif will do it.

Comment: Simon, still a bit of clarification in the question would be nice. Makes it more usefule for future users.

Comment: @daleif Any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B ^^^^^^

Comment: @cfr Like a wasteland in here. Any idea what to do?

Comment: @daleif Do you want to answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Or community wiki? If daleif is not around?

Comment: @cfr I don't feel like writing something here.

Comment: @Johannes_B Close as unclear?

Comment: @cfr Seems to be an idea. Voted